# mousewheel and if statements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

What I'm trying to do is make it so when you try to scroll up or down it calls a function that changes the page. My body has `overflow:hidden`.

I'm using the jquery plugin called https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel'>mousewheel

This is my code:

```
$('#body').on('mousewheel', function(event) {

  if( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ) {
    //scroll down
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 1') scrollDown(2);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 2') scrollDown(3);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 3') scrollDown(4);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 4') scrollDown(5);
  } else {
    //scroll up
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 2') scrollUp(1);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 3') scrollUp(2);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 4') scrollUp(3);
    if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 5') scrollUp(4);
  }
  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;

});
```

For some reason it works when scrolling up but when you scroll down it goes straight to page 5 (the last one). When i added `console.log(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML)` to each if statement for scrolling down it logged this:

```
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
```

I don't understand why it would work scrolling up but not down. I know that the function being called (scrollDown) isn't the problem as it works when called from the console.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `scrollDown()` function alters the page value, the solution is pretty clear:

```
if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 1') scrollDown(2);
if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 2') scrollDown(3);
if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 3') scrollDown(4);
if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 4') scrollDown(5);
```

If you're on page 1, the code calls `scrollDown(2)`, moving you to page 2.  Then the code immediately checks to see if you're on page 2, and if so it scrolls to page 3.  The process repeats until you get to page 5.

Things would be a lot cleaner if you kept track of the page explicitly instead of looking at the page text. However the simplest thing to do with the code you have is add `else`:

```
if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 1') scrollDown(2);
else if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 2') scrollDown(3);
else if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 3') scrollDown(4);
else if(document.getElementById('pgcount').innerHTML == 'Page 4') scrollDown(5);
```

Comment: scrollDown() does alter the page value. It's only called when you scroll down so if you're on page 1 and scroll then you'd be on page 2 until you scrolled again.

Comment: @BenWelch no, after calling `scrollDown(2)`, what's the next line of code that's executed? It's the `if` statement that checks for page 2.  When `scrollDown(2)` returns, you're still in that mousewheel handler code.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan because of how the `if` statements are ordered. Look at the code. In the scroll up case, the first `if` tests for page 2. If that is the current page, then the page is set to 1, and the subsequent 3 `if` tests fail.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan no he's right. Thanks you. Scroll up works because when the correct if statement is called, then the if statement which would have had the effect of going up again has already been called.

Comment: ok thumbs up for @Pointy, and you should be more clearer next time :P